# React JS - Unable to find an element by data-testid

Tags: reactjs

I am writing tests for React code where I get the error

```
Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="primary-cta"]
```

I actually want this to be for negative test case where the button is not displayed in the page

```
const renewButton = getByTestId('primary-cta');
expect(renewButton).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

So I am using "not.toBeInTheDocument();" , but I am getting the error

Can anyone pleaase help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `queryByTestId` if the element may not be present. `queryBy*` methods return `null` if the element is not found.

`getBy*` methods throw errors in case there are no matching elements. Hence, the error you are getting.

Relevant docs: [Link](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/)

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted if it worked! :)